# Chi-square contrast tests with R

Tags: chi-squared-test, contrasts

I have Group A, B, C.
My hypotheses are"

1) proportions of C are different from proportions of A (=independance) 
2) proportions of C are different from proportions of B (=independance) 
3) proportions of A are NOT different from proportions of B (=NO independance)

Is there something like post-hoc contrasts for chi-squared, so I can test all my hypotheses in ONE modell and not have alpha inflation?

Intuitively I would test C against a composite of A and B but that still doesnt test if A is different/independent

There is a [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464680/is-there-a-pair-wise-posthoc-comparisons-for-the-chi-square-test-in-r) regarding this topic, but there wasn't an answer.

Comment: You might be interested in these questions and related pointers: [Multiple Chi-Squared Tests](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1133/930), [How to carry out multiple post-hoc chi-square tests on a 2 X 3 table?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9685/930), [Has anyone used the Marascuillo procedure for comparing multiple proportions?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3526/930).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R Package 'pairwise.prop.test()' does the post-hoc job. One can also define several methods of adjusting p-value. However, this is only a post-hoc test and no planned comparisons.